# SQL NOT LIKE not functioning properly

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I am unable to figure out why the NOT LIKE operators are not working properly. I have 34 `sample_name` in the database that start with NT but it only get rid of some, and not other. When I try searching with `LIKE ('NT%)`, it search them all. Below is what I have.

```
WHERE
    full.full_id IN ('272', '273')
OR  full.full_id IN ('567', '686')
AND random.sample_name NOT LIKE ('NT%')
```

Comment: I think it should be `NOT LIKE 'NT%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extraneous `,` in the `IN` list and you are missing the `'` at the end of your NOT LIKE statement. The statement should look like the following:

```
WHERE full.full_id IN ('272', '273', '567', '686')
AND random.sample_name NOT LIKE ('NT%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, however, I mistyped before. Please check the correct code now. This still doesn't work. It only removes few records while retaining others. My hunch is that the `OR` operator is causing some problem here because if I remove that statement and put all the `full_id` in one statement then it works. Any insight on why is that happening?

Comment: If it is working with removing the OR statement, then why don't you just remove it taking the whole list in a single one? Do you have any special purpose?

Comment: Yes, that is just one example. Even if I am using other columns from other tables, it still creates the problem. In this case, I am using `OR` for the same column because there are too many values to put in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in the code you have posted.  I am going to guess that you intend:

```
WHERE full.full_id IN (272, 273) AND
      random.sample_name NOT LIKE 'NT%'
```

Notes:

- No comma in the `IN` list.
- Terminating single quote on `LIKE` pattern
- Don't use single quotes for constants, if the column is a number (use single quotes only for string and date constants).
- No parentheses are needed around the `LIKE` pattern (although that is not a syntax issue)